# Loop through files in a directory, add a date column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

All of my files have the following titles and they stretch back for a few years. I want to be able to read each file and then add the date from the file name as a column.

Filetype as of 2015-04-01.csv

```
path = 'C:\\Users\\'  
filelist = os.listdir(path)     #All of my .csv files I am working with
file_count = len(filelist)      #I thought I could do a for loop and use this as a the range
df = Series(filelist)           #I just added this because I couldn't get the date from a list
date_name = df.str[15:-4]       #This gives me the date
```

So what I have tried is:

```
for file in filelist:
    df = pd.read_csv(file)
```

Now I want to take the date_name from the file name and add a column called date. Every file is exactly the same but I want to track changes over time and the only date is found just on the name of the file.

Then I will append it.

```
path = 'C:\\Users\\'
filelist = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")
frame = pd.DataFrame()
list = []
for file in filelist:
    df = pd.read_csv(file)
    list_.append(df)
frame = pd.concat(list)
```

How can I add the date_name to the file/dataframe? 1) Read the file, 2) Add the date column based on the file name, 3) Read the next file, 4) Add the date column, 5) Append, 6) Repeat for all files in the path

Edit---
I think I got something to work - is this the best way? Can someone explain what the list = [] is doing and such is doing?

```
path = 'C:\\Users\\'
filelist = os.listdir(path) 
list = []
frame = pd.DataFrame()
for file in filelist:
    df2 = pd.read_csv(path+file)
    date_name = file[15:-4]
    df2['Date'] = date_name
    list.append(df2)
frame = pd.concat(list)
```

Comment: Hi in your `edit` what does `file[15:-4]` for do???

Comment: This is a very old question, but it was just grabbing the date from the filename. Like the filename was something-2020-01-01.xlsx, for example, and it was only taking the date portion from that name.

Comment: Thats exactly what I am hoping to do with csv files. Except my csv files are named `01_03` for January 3rd... Is there anywhere I could read about how you did that?

Comment: Actually thru trial and error I figured it out I need `file[1:-4]` thanks for your post!

Answer (score 3):

This seems like a reasonable way to do it. The `pd.concat` takes a list of pandas objects and concatenates them. `append` adds each `frame` to the list as you loop through the files. I see two things to change though.

1. You don't need `frame = pd.DataFrame()`. It is not doing anything as you are appending `dataframes` to the list.
2. I'd change the name of the variable `list` to something else. Maybe `frames` as it is descriptive of the contents and doesn't already mean something.

Comment: Yes, indeed - plus 'list' is a python keyword. Also, I don't like the idea of filename[15:-4], instead filename.split('.')[0] is more portable - if for whatever reasons, the convention to name csv changes (or some csvs are in an older convention and some are in newer convention).

Comment: The file name is 'XYZ as of 2015-05-30.csv'. I am grabbing the date and then making a column in the file with that date.

Comment: What does the list = []  do?

Comment: it creates an empty list

Comment: as would `frames =[]` specifically it assigns an empty list to a variable name