# Add date column to each excel workbook depending on the name of the workbook. Using python and pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I'm attempting to add a date column to each row that contains data from an excel workbook.

Not quite sure how to get started, using python and pandas. (Still pretty new at python)

**The files in the folder are setup as follows:**

```
| Folder Name |
|------|
|All GL Accounts Jan 2020.xlsx|
|All GL Accounts Feb 2020.xlsx|
|All GL Accounts Mar 2020.xlsx|
ETC.
```

I would like to read in the ending of the name on the excel *Jan 2020.xlsx and look it up in a list that contains a formatted date such as: 1/31/2020.

I would need the script to iterate through the entire folder and make changes to every month of the each year and add a date column for each row that contains data.

Thank you all in advance for help!!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30405420/loop-through-files-in-a-directory-add-a-date-column-in-pandas

Comment: Awesome! Thank you! I had trouble finding anything before.

Comment: happy coding :)

Comment: The one thing is they are not .csv files. will this make a difference?

Comment: change `pd.read_csv` for `pd.read_excel` and you're good to go

Answer (score 0):

So shout out to [@Yuca](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9754169/yuca) for pointing me in the right direction. I used some knowledge I learned from fnmatch and implemented it in my script.

Not sure if this was the best way to do things, but it is running now!

If anyone has any thing they would like to add, I'm always up to learn more.

```
import os
import pandas as pd
from fnmatch import fnmatch

date_dict = {
    'Jan 2020':r'01/01/2020',
    'Feb 2020':r'02/01/2020',
    'Mar 2020':r'03/01/2020',
    'Apr 2020':r'04/01/2020',
    'May 2020':r'05/01/2020',
    'Jun 2020':r'06/01/2020',
    'Jul 2020':r'07/01/2020',
    'Aug 2020':r'08/01/2020',
    'Sep 2020':r'09/01/2020',
    'Oct 2020':r'10/01/2020',
    'Nov 2020':r'11/01/2020',
    'Dec 2020':r'12/01/2020',
    }

date_list = (
    'Jan 2020',
    'Feb 2020',
    'Mar 2020',
    'Apr 2020',
    'May 2020',
    'Jun 2020',
    'Jul 2020',
    'Aug 2020',
    'Sep 2020',
    'Oct 2020',
    'Nov 2020',
    'Dec 2020'
    )


patterns = [(date, f"*{date}.xlsx") for date in date_list]

path = r'file_path'
filelist = os.listdir(path) 
for file in filelist:
    print(file)
    for date, pattern in patterns:
        print(pattern)
        print(date)
        if fnmatch(file, pattern):
            frames = []
            df = pd.read_excel(path+'/'+file)
            date_name = date_dict[date]
            df['Date'] = date_name
            print('Matched: ' + file)
            frames.append(df)
            frame = pd.concat(frames)
            frame.to_excel(path +'\\_New_'+ file, index = False)
            break
```